# Remove duplicate entries from SQL COUNT CASE WHEN query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which is counting the types of submissions I have.  The issue is that some documents (docNo) are submitted more than once, I only want to count the most recent of each docNo submitted (dateSubmitted).

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 6 THEN 1 END) AS proRev,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 5 THEN 1 END) AS proRan,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 7 THEN 1 END) AS proRej,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 4 THEN 1 END) AS proInRev,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 6 AND D.FS = 1 THEN 1 END) AS proRevF,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 5 AND D.FS = 1 THEN 1 END) AS proRanF,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 7 AND D.FS = 1 THEN 1 END) AS proRejF,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 4 AND D.FS = 1 THEN 1 END) AS proInRevF,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 6 AND D.FS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS proRevS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 5 AND D.FS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS proRanS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 7 AND D.FS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS proRejS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN S.receivedStatus = 4 AND D.FS = 2 THEN 1 END) AS proInRevS
  FROM submissions S
    LEFT JOIN cxprocedure C ON C.id = S.proTag
    LEFT JOIN discipline D ON D.disciplineID = C.discipline
```

I tried adding:

```
GROUP BY S.docNo 
HAVING MAX(S.dateSubmitted)
```

That didn't do it.  I tried changing the FROM to be:

```
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT docNo, MAX(dateSubmitted) FROM submissions) AS S
```

And that didn't work either.

Am new at putting a subquery in from, so be gentle, just need to figure out how to do it, but I can't figure out what it should be.  Can anyone provide assistance to help me work this out so I am good moving forward.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing subquery and aggregation in your syntax.

I would create a (sub)query with the different cases based on your criteria, like so:

```
SELECT
  S.docNo,
  S.receivedStatus,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 6, 1, 0) AS proRev,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 5, 1, 0) AS proRan,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 7, 1, 0) AS proRej,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 4, 1, 0) AS proInRev,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 6 AND D.FS = 1, 1, 0) AS proRevF,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 5 AND D.FS = 1, 1, 0) AS proRanF,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 7 AND D.FS = 1, 1, 0) AS proRejF,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 4 AND D.FS = 1, 1, 0) AS proInRevF,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 6 AND D.FS = 2, 1, 0) AS proRevS,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 5 AND D.FS = 2, 1, 0) AS proRanS,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 7 AND D.FS = 2, 1, 0) AS proRejS,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 4 AND D.FS = 2, 1, 0) AS proInRevS
FROM submissions S
  LEFT JOIN cxprocedure C ON C.id = S.proTag
  LEFT JOIN discipline D ON D.disciplineID = C.discipline
JOIN
  -- subquery to determine the MAX submit date per docNo
  (SELECT docNo, MAX(dateSubmitted) AS maxdate 
  FROM submissions GROUP BY docNo
  ) AS md -- maxdate
ON S.docNo = md.docNo AND s.dateSubmitted = md.maxdate
```

By using the subquery in the JOIN you can filter out just the youngest entries per docNo (if I understand your datamodel correctly). This of course ONLY works if the combination of [docNo] + [dateSubmitted] is unique or [dateSubmitted] is a timestamp.

Then you run that query and if the results are correct, I would encapsulate that as subquery:

```
SELECT
  SUM(source.proRev) AS proRev,
  SUM(source.proRan) AS proRan,
  SUM(source.proRej) AS proRej,
  SUM(source.proInRev) AS proInRev,
  SUM(source.proRevF) AS proRevF,
  SUM(source.proRanF) AS proRanF,
  SUM(source.proRejF) AS proRejF,
  SUM(source.proInRevF) AS proInRevF,
  SUM(source.proRevS) AS proRevS,
  SUM(source.proRanS) AS proRanS,
  SUM(source.proRejS) AS proRejS,
  SUM(source.proInRev) AS proInRevS
FROM

(SELECT
  S.docNo,
  S.receivedStatus,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 6, 1, 0) AS proRev,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 5, 1, 0) AS proRan,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 7, 1, 0) AS proRej,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 4, 1, 0) AS proInRev,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 6 AND D.FS = 1, 1, 0) AS proRevF,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 5 AND D.FS = 1, 1, 0) AS proRanF,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 7 AND D.FS = 1, 1, 0) AS proRejF,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 4 AND D.FS = 1, 1, 0) AS proInRevF,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 6 AND D.FS = 2, 1, 0) AS proRevS,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 5 AND D.FS = 2, 1, 0) AS proRanS,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 7 AND D.FS = 2, 1, 0) AS proRejS,
  IF(S.receivedStatus = 4 AND D.FS = 2, 1, 0) AS proInRevS
FROM submissions S
  LEFT JOIN cxprocedure C ON C.id = S.proTag
  LEFT JOIN discipline D ON D.disciplineID = C.discipline
JOIN
  (SELECT docNo, MAX(dateSubmitted) AS maxdate 
  FROM submissions GROUP BY docNo
  ) AS md -- maxdate
ON S.docNo = md.docNo AND s.dateSubmitted = md.maxdate
) AS source
```

Personally I would watch out using SELECT DISTINCT in combination with COUNT (or other aggregational functions), because it can hide possible mistakes in the grouping of records.

Edit : sorry my answering and editing was all over the place. First read the question wrong and then made mistakes while editing.

Comment: Thanks Sam020, I will take this away and try it and let you know.  I appreciate your explanation as well to help me understand the process.  And you are correct, the docNo and dateSubmitted are unique.

Comment: ok, So I believe I understand this, however there is an error with 'source' it seems.  There is a missing , just after SUM(source.proInRev) AS proInRevS in case anyone is looking at the code, just a typo, so no big deal.

When I run the query it tells me "#1109 - Unknown table 'source' in field list" I see the source is declared right at the end, but doesn't seem to be getting read by the initial sums.

Comment: yes ... FROM is missing in front of the subquery ... pffff I need coffee

Comment: oh yes, even I should have seen that, lol.

Comment: Works perfect, appreciate your help and the explanation @Sam020